# Spark: unable to load native-hadoop library for platform

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to start with Spark. I have Hadoop (3.3.1) and Spark (3.2.2) in my library. I have set the SPARK_HOME, PATH, HADOOP_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to their respective paths. I am also running JDK 17 (echo and -version work fine in the terminal).

Yet, I still get the following error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/10/25 17:17:07 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x1f508f09) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x1f508f09
  at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
  ... 55 elided
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.2.0
      /_/
         
Using Scala version 2.12.15 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 17.0.1)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: `unable to load native-hadoop library for platform` is just a warning, not an error and normally doesn't indicate any problems. The actual error is the stuff below it. Does Spark die after this or can you use the console?

Comment: Hmmm oke. I thought it had to do why I get the Spark error (not found: value Spark). I can still use the console, but whatever I try, it always falls back on not found: value Spark. E.g. from the Spark bin folder: val strings = spark.read.text("../README.md")

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386153/why-does-spark-shell-fail-with-error-not-found-value-spark/45517043

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Java 17 isn't supported - Spark runs on Java 8/11 (source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/).

So install Java 11 and point Spark to that.

The warning `unable to load native-hadoop library for platform` is quite common and doesn't mean that anything's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type this command  --> **gedit .bashrc**

Ensure that you are added the **native  after lib** as shown below

```
export HADOOP_OPTS = "-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
```

and **Save** the file and type this command in terminal **source ~/.bashrc**

Try this it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac and installed openjdk@11 through brew, it gives you some warnings and tells you what to do.
I have been facing the same issue until I did these steps:

For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with

`sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk`

If you need to have openjdk@11 first in your PATH, run:

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

For compilers to find openjdk@11 you may need to set:

`export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/include"`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue recently, my issue was with java version. need to use java 11/17 for spark version >3.2.0, [refer documentation here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#:%7E:text=Spark%20runs%20on%20Java%208/11/17%2C%20Scala%202.12/2.13).