# WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform. Windows 10

Tags: apache-spark

I have installed spark on Windows 10, just as guide procedure. But I have this warning messages, and I cant do import pyspark and findspark from jupiter notebook. I can't either see spark pages in localhost 4040.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark: unable to load native-hadoop library for platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69710694/spark-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-platform)

Comment: Please always post text instead of screen shots of error messages. They are not searchable and therefore help no one.