# SparkSession.builder throws error by JavaSparkContext with java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am using the below snippet to initiate a spark session:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from datetime import datetime

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    .config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false")
)
```

However, it throws the following error:

```
 An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x3c60b7e7) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x3c60b7e7
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I have tried it locally and by using aws glue development endpoint, however, the same snippet throwing same error.

Comment: I would suggest refering [to this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69710694/spark-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-platform) for the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark: unable to load native-hadoop library for platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69710694/spark-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-platform)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JDK 8 to compile. This helped me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).